# The type of dispatch in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Since I imagine in typescript we should avoid as much as possible using 'any' types I am rewriting all the anys a bit to transform them into more precise types but I am facing a problem when I try to change the type 'any' of the dispatch function of react redux. I don't know what to replace it with?

**themeActions.ts :**

```js
export const SWITCH_THEME: string = "SWITCH_THEME";

export const switchTheme = (theme: string) => {

    return (dispatch: any) => {
        
        dispatch({ type: SWITCH_THEME, theme: theme })
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);

    }

}
```

**themeReducer.ts :**

```js
import {SWITCH_THEME} from './themeActions';

const initialState = {
    theme: localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark' ? 'dark' : 'light'
}

const themeReducer = (state = initialState, action: {type: string, theme: string}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SWITCH_THEME:
            return {
                ...state,
                theme: action.theme
            }
            default:
                return state
    }
}

export default themeReducer;
```

Comment: Well, look at how you're using it. You're calling it, so maybe a function type? Then think about the parameter and return types.

Comment: I replaced with "return (dispatch: Function) =>" in the themeActions.ts, the code is valid also when you say return type and parameters what do you mean?

For the parameters, they are visible in themeActions so it's okay {type: SWITCH_THEME, theme: theme}?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `import { Dispatch } from 'redux'`

```js
export const switchTheme = (theme: string) => {

    return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        
        dispatch({ type: SWITCH_THEME, theme: theme })
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);

    }

}
```

Comment: Note to any `redux-thunk` users: you need to `import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk'` as the standard definition of `Dispatch` from redux does not support thunks.

Comment: @Linda Paiste nice catch, as always!